# Not able to push Java Spring Application to CF (failed to start accepting connections)

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I have problems to push Spring applications to our cloud foundry. 
Application used for this test are 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-sample-app-spring 
and hello-spring-cloud

If, I'm running cf push, I get the following output.

```
Using manifest file C:\Developement\Workspace\other\cf-sample-app-spring\manifest.yml

Creating app cf-spring in org bt / space developement as admin...
OK

Creating route cf-spring-revenued-wayside.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net...
OK

Binding cf-spring-revenued-wayside.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net to cf-spring...
OK

Uploading cf-spring...
Uploading app files from: C:\Developement\Workspace\other\cf-sample-app-spring
Uploading 2.5M, 53 files
Done uploading
OK

Starting app cf-spring in org bt / space developement as admin...
----- Downloaded app package (1.3M)
    ----- Java Buildpack Version: 5649c99 (offline) | github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#5649c99
----- Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_101 from java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_101.tar.gz (found in c
       Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.2s)
----- Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.2_RELEASE from java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/mem
2.0.2_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
       Memory Settings: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64M -Xss228K -Xms317161K -XX:MetaspaceSize=64M -Xmx317161K
----- Downloading Spring Boot CLI 1.4.0_RELEASE from java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/spring-boot-cli/spring-boot-cli-1.4.0_RELEASE.tar.g
he)
       Expanding Spring Boot CLI to .java-buildpack/spring_boot_cli (0.0s)

----- Uploading droplet (54M)

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start app timeout

TIP: Application must be listening on the right port. Instead of hard coding the port, use the $PORT environment variable.
```

The log file shows like this.

```
2016-10-05T13:37:20.03+0000 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Spring Boot CLI to .java-buildpack/spring_boot_cli (0.0s)

2016-10-05T13:37:20.90+0000 [STG/0]      ERR

2016-10-05T13:37:23.33+0000 [API/0]      OUT Created app with guid e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2

2016-10-05T13:37:24.30+0000 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2 ({"route"="f68255dc-3af6-4884-911a-aedfad67f608", :verb="add", :relation=:routes, :related_guid="f68255dc-3af6-4884-911a-aedfad67f608"})

2016-10-05T13:37:29.30+0000 [STG/0]      OUT ----- Uploading droplet (54M)

2016-10-05T13:37:32.90+0000 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2 ({"state"="STARTED"})

2016-10-05T13:37:35.59+0000 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2

2016-10-05T13:38:38.73+0000 [DEA/0]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

2016-10-05T13:38:38.74+0000 [App/0]      ERR

2016-10-05T13:38:38.74+0000 [App/0]      OUT Resolving dependencies..

2016-10-05T13:38:53.80+0000 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2

2016-10-05T13:38:54.97+0000 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2 payload: {"cc_partition"="default", "droplet"="e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2", "version"="5d9c9099-f439-4452-b1ee-8404f91e8913", "instance"="733bbdb6ac0a4fee82da2f64bfbba25c", "index"=0, "reason"="CRASHED", "exit_status"=-1, "exit_description"="failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=1475674718}

2016-10-05T13:39:56.74+0000 [DEA/0]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

2016-10-05T13:39:56.75+0000 [App/0]      ERR
```

I have read that the Port is wrong, but sample application should work in my opinion.

PHP is working.

Update:

Output cf events

time                          event              actor       description

```
2016-10-06T09:10:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T09:08:20.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T09:06:58.00+0200   audit.app.update   admin       state: STARTED
2016-10-06T09:06:56.00+0200   audit.app.update   admin       state: STOPPED
2016-10-06T09:06:49.00+0200   audit.app.update   admin       instances: 1, memory: 512, environment_json: PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN
2016-10-06T09:05:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T08:47:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T08:29:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T08:11:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T07:53:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T07:35:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T07:17:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T06:59:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T06:41:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T06:23:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T06:05:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T05:47:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T05:29:15.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T05:11:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T04:53:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T04:35:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T04:17:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T03:59:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T03:41:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T03:23:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T03:05:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T02:47:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T02:29:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T02:11:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T01:53:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T01:35:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T01:17:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T00:59:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T00:41:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T00:23:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-06T00:05:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T23:47:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T23:29:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T23:11:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T22:53:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T22:35:14.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T22:17:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T21:59:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T21:41:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T21:23:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T21:05:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T20:47:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T20:29:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T20:11:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
2016-10-05T19:53:13.00+0200   app.crash          cf-spring   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to accept connections within health check timeo
ut, exit_status: -1
```

And here are the last dea_next.log

```
bosh_in5vm1wdj@395258af-d998-4316-8c8e-668a6e22ca9d:~$ tail /var/vcap/sys/log/dea_next/dea_next.log
    {"timestamp":1476082579.1567905,"message":"hm9000.heartbeat.accepted","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Bootstrap","data":{},"thread_id":47185769561460,"fiber_id":47185766460580,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/utils/hm9000.rb","lineno":49,"method":"handle_http_response"}
    {"timestamp":1476082584.8020003,"message":"nats.message.received","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Nats","data":{"subject":"dea.find.droplet","data":{"droplet":"e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2","states":["STARTING","RUNNING"],"version":"0609dc18-0df5-4fd8-9de9-b3030717b71f"}},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/nats.rb","lineno":143,"method":"handle_incoming_message"}
    {"timestamp":1476082586.8324697,"message":"nats.message.received","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Nats","data":{"subject":"dea.find.droplet","data":{"droplet":"e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2","include_stats":true,"states":["RUNNING"],"version":"0609dc18-0df5-4fd8-9de9-b3030717b71f"}},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/nats.rb","lineno":143,"method":"handle_incoming_message"}
    {"timestamp":1476082589.1587467,"message":"Reaping orphaned containers","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Bootstrap","data":{},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/bootstrap.rb","lineno":236,"method":"reap_orphaned_containers"}
    {"timestamp":1476082589.1603103,"message":"hm9000.heartbeat.sending","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Bootstrap","data":{"destination":"https://listener-hm9000.service.cf.internal:5335/dea/heartbeat"},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/utils/hm9000.rb","lineno":29,"method":"send_heartbeat"}
    {"timestamp":1476082589.1947746,"message":"hm9000.heartbeat.accepted","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Bootstrap","data":{},"thread_id":47185769561920,"fiber_id":47185767135580,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/utils/hm9000.rb","lineno":49,"method":"handle_http_response"}
    {"timestamp":1476082593.9196806,"message":"nats.message.received","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Nats","data":{"subject":"dea.find.droplet","data":{"droplet":"e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2","states":["STARTING","RUNNING"],"version":"0609dc18-0df5-4fd8-9de9-b3030717b71f"}},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/nats.rb","lineno":143,"method":"handle_incoming_message"}
    {"timestamp":1476082595.9557447,"message":"nats.message.received","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Nats","data":{"subject":"dea.find.droplet","data":{"droplet":"e1ff2dcf-749f-4c88-b094-6d5d69f7f9e2","include_stats":true,"states":["RUNNING"],"version":"0609dc18-0df5-4fd8-9de9-b3030717b71f"}},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/nats.rb","lineno":143,"method":"handle_incoming_message"}
    {"timestamp":1476082599.1620932,"message":"hm9000.heartbeat.sending","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Bootstrap","data":{"destination":"https://listener-hm9000.service.cf.internal:5335/dea/heartbeat"},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47185767308020,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/utils/hm9000.rb","lineno":29,"method":"send_heartbeat"}
    {"timestamp":1476082599.1665351,"message":"hm9000.heartbeat.accepted","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Bootstrap","data":{},"thread_id":47185769561780,"fiber_id":47185766851560,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/utils/hm9000.rb","lineno":49,"method":"handle_http_response"}

And the dir_server.log

    bosh_in5vm1wdj@395258af-d998-4316-8c8e-668a6e22ca9d:~$ tail /var/vcap/sys/log/dea_next/dir_server.log
```

Here are the Tail during deploying

```
{"timestamp":1476884074.7819035,"message":"droplet.unhealthy","log_level":"warn","source":"Dea::Instance","data":
{"attributes":
{"stack":"cflinuxfs2","prod":false,"executableFile":"deprecated","limits":
{"mem":1024,"disk":1024,"fds":16384},"cc_partition":"default","console":false,"debug":null,"start_command":null,"health_check_timeout":null,"vcap_application":
{"limits":
{"fds":16384,"mem":1024,"disk":1024},"application_name":"cf-spring","application_uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"name":"cf-spring","space_name":"test","space_id":"168d6627-ad82-49e1-9999-acbdd42a2ac8","uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"users":null,"application_id":"f0120647-bb59-4a18-8ba9-80de3f9d6bf5","version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b","application_version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b"},"egress_network_rules":[
{"destination":"0.0.0.0/0","ports":"53","protocol":"tcp"},
{"destination":"0.0.0.0/0","ports":"53","protocol":"udp"},
{"destination":"10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"0.0.0.0-9.255.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"11.0.0.0-169.253.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"169.255.0.0-172.15.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"172.32.0.0-192.167.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"192.169.0.0-255.255.255.255","protocol":"all"}],"instance_index":0,"application_version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b","application_name":"cf-spring","application_uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"application_id":"f0120647-bb59-4a18-8ba9-80de3f9d6bf5","droplet_sha1":"b2c98c44c86eedb098c0988be3e91c4c7e2ff029","instance_id":"3d26030ee9eb4c7c999693b85a54d33d","private_instance_id":"cd68d607a88c4d628b8185b8912741ca041361aa74a74cef85735e9cb61d165a","state":"STARTING","state_timestamp":1476884011.448288,"state_born_timestamp":1476884011.445944,"state_starting_timestamp":1476884011.4482913,"warden_handle":"19tknch89o4","warden_job_id":4125}},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47186083846080,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/starting/instance.rb","lineno":525,"method":"block in start"}

{"timestamp":1476884074.7846763,"message":"Saving snapshot took: 0.001s","log_level":"debug","source":"Dea::Snapshot","data":
{},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47186083846420,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/snapshot.rb","lineno":41,"method":"save"}

{"timestamp":1476884074.7849338,"message":"instance.start.failed with error failed to accept connections within health check timeout","log_level":"warn","source":"Dea::Instance","data":
{"attributes":
{"stack":"cflinuxfs2","prod":false,"executableFile":"deprecated","limits":
{"mem":1024,"disk":1024,"fds":16384},"cc_partition":"default","console":false,"debug":null,"start_command":null,"health_check_timeout":null,"vcap_application":
{"limits":
{"fds":16384,"mem":1024,"disk":1024},"application_name":"cf-spring","application_uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"name":"cf-spring","space_name":"test","space_id":"168d6627-ad82-49e1-9999-acbdd42a2ac8","uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"users":null,"application_id":"f0120647-bb59-4a18-8ba9-80de3f9d6bf5","version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b","application_version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b"},"egress_network_rules":[
{"destination":"0.0.0.0/0","ports":"53","protocol":"tcp"},
{"destination":"0.0.0.0/0","ports":"53","protocol":"udp"},
{"destination":"10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"0.0.0.0-9.255.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"11.0.0.0-169.253.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"169.255.0.0-172.15.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"172.32.0.0-192.167.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"192.169.0.0-255.255.255.255","protocol":"all"}],"instance_index":0,"application_version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b","application_name":"cf-spring","application_uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"application_id":"f0120647-bb59-4a18-8ba9-80de3f9d6bf5","droplet_sha1":"b2c98c44c86eedb098c0988be3e91c4c7e2ff029","instance_id":"3d26030ee9eb4c7c999693b85a54d33d","private_instance_id":"cd68d607a88c4d628b8185b8912741ca041361aa74a74cef85735e9cb61d165a","state":"CRASHED","state_timestamp":1476884074.7826014,"state_born_timestamp":1476884011.445944,"state_starting_timestamp":1476884011.4482913,"warden_handle":"19tknch89o4","warden_job_id":4125,"state_crashed_timestamp":1476884074.7826064},"duration":63.335018136,"error":"failed to accept connections within health check timeout","backtrace":["/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/promise.rb:81:in `resolve'","/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/promise.rb:14:in `block in resolve'"]},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47186083846420,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/task.rb","lineno":105,"method":"block in resolve_and_log"}

{"timestamp":1476884074.8929827,"message":"droplet.warden.link.completed","log_level":"warn","source":"Dea::Instance","data":
{"attributes":
{"stack":"cflinuxfs2","prod":false,"executableFile":"deprecated","limits":
{"mem":1024,"disk":1024,"fds":16384},"cc_partition":"default","console":false,"debug":null,"start_command":null,"health_check_timeout":null,"vcap_application":
{"limits":
{"fds":16384,"mem":1024,"disk":1024},"application_name":"cf-spring","application_uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"name":"cf-spring","space_name":"test","space_id":"168d6627-ad82-49e1-9999-acbdd42a2ac8","uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"users":null,"application_id":"f0120647-bb59-4a18-8ba9-80de3f9d6bf5","version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b","application_version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b"},"egress_network_rules":[
{"destination":"0.0.0.0/0","ports":"53","protocol":"tcp"},
{"destination":"0.0.0.0/0","ports":"53","protocol":"udp"},
{"destination":"10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"0.0.0.0-9.255.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"11.0.0.0-169.253.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"169.255.0.0-172.15.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"172.32.0.0-192.167.255.255","protocol":"all"},
{"destination":"192.169.0.0-255.255.255.255","protocol":"all"}],"instance_index":0,"application_version":"01e12042-3bb4-410d-973c-ff1aa57c6b5b","application_name":"cf-spring","application_uris":["cf-spring-unreputable-catstick.apps.de.cloudfoundry.it-platforms.net"],"application_id":"f0120647-bb59-4a18-8ba9-80de3f9d6bf5","droplet_sha1":"b2c98c44c86eedb098c0988be3e91c4c7e2ff029","instance_id":"3d26030ee9eb4c7c999693b85a54d33d","private_instance_id":"cd68d607a88c4d628b8185b8912741ca041361aa74a74cef85735e9cb61d165a","state":"CRASHED","state_timestamp":1476884074.7826014,"state_born_timestamp":1476884011.445944,"state_starting_timestamp":1476884011.4482913,"warden_handle":"19tknch89o4","warden_job_id":4125,"state_crashed_timestamp":1476884074.7826064,"instance_path":"/var/vcap/data/dea_next/crashes/3d26030ee9eb4c7c999693b85a54d33d"},"exit_status":255,"exit_description":"app instance exited"},"thread_id":47185756385560,"fiber_id":47186085543500,"process_id":5387,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/lib/dea/starting/instance.rb","lineno":699,"method":"block in link"}
```

Comment: Can you also post the output from `cf events`?

Comment: Sure. I have edit the question with the output of cf events

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory assigned to the application in manifest.yml? Do you have access to the DEA logs?

Comment: I have doubled the memory from 512MB to 1024 MB. Same problem. I should have access to the DEA logs. Where can I find them?

Comment: If the DEA logs are in the Runner. This logs  (dea_ctl.log) etc. are empty

Comment: That's the DEA control logs, there should be a directory alongside that file called dea or dea_ng, take a look in there.

Comment: Found the DEA logs. I have added them to the post.

Comment: @DanHigham do you have an idea?

Comment: You might want to try running your application with Diego.  The Diego logger binds to your application stdout/err much quicker than DEA does.  This will make sure you're not missing any early startup error messages in your loggregator stream  that might clue you into what is going on.

Comment: I'm working on another CF installation with Diego. This Diego installation is not ready for development.

Comment: If you tail the DEA log file whilst deploying, you should see why the app is failing. This seems to be just a few lines of the file.

Comment: @DanHigham I have added the new logs. Sorry it is a long log.

Comment: Have you been able to get anything running on this Cloud Foundry instance at all?

Comment: Yes PHP Projects are working fine.

Comment: How about a different example spring app? Like spring-music

Comment: I tried Spring Hello Cloud, Spring Music and Spring Sample App.